# Provide a file name prefix in Hive INSERT

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hive

I have a Hive script script that moves data from DynamoDB into S3,

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE ddb-table (hash_key string, sort_key string, value string)
    STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBStorageHandler'
    TBLPROPERTIES (
        "dynamodb.table.name" = "ddb-table",
        "dynamodb.column.mapping" = "hash:hash,range:range,data:data"
    );

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE s3-bucket (hash string, range string, data string)
    PARTITIONED BY (hash_key STRING)
    LOCATION 's3://some-bucket-name/';


INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE s3-bucket PARTITION (hash_key)
    SELECT sort_key string, value string, hash_key string
    FROM ddb-table;
```

However the I want to control the file name format. I want to use the `hash_key` as well as other values as the filenames prefix in S3. Is this possible?